# PHP make option selected

Tags: php, html, drop-down-menu

I have this dropdown:

```
<tr>
<td><label for="isOpen">Is The Dome Open?</label></td>
<td><select name="isOpen" id="isOpen"><option value="Yes">Yes</option><option value="No">No</option></select></td>
</tr>
```

and I have this value from a database: $row[1] which is equal to 1 and I have this PHP code:

```
if($row[1] == 1){
    $isOpen = 'Yes';
}else{
    $isOpen = 'No';
}
```

My question is how do I get the selected value to be the value from the database?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

like this

```
<tr>
    <td><label for="isOpen">Is The Dome Open?</label></td>
    <td><select name="isOpen" id="isOpen">
    <option value="Yes" <?php if($isOpen == 'Yes'){echo selected="selected"; ?>>Yes</option>
    <option value="No" <?php if($isOpen == 'No'){echo selected="selected"; ?>>No</option></select></td>
    </tr>
```

or

```
    <tr>
        <td><label for="isOpen">Is The Dome Open?</label></td>
        <td><select name="isOpen" id="isOpen">
        <option value="Yes" <?php if($row[1] == 1){echo selected="selected"; ?>>Yes</option>
        <option value="No" <?php if($row[1] == 0){echo selected="selected"; ?>>No</option></select></

td>
    </tr>
```

Answer (score 0):

If you have PHP short tags activated you can simple use

```
<tr>
  <td><label for="isOpen">Is The Dome Open?</label></td>
  <td>
    <select name="isOpen" id="isOpen">
      <option value="Yes" <?=$row[1] ? 'selected' : '' ?> >Yes</option>
      <option value="No" <?=$row[1] ? '' : 'selected' ?> >No</option>
    </select>
  </td>
</tr>
```

Answer (score 0):

You can pre-select an item with "selected" :

```
<select>
  <option value="Yes" selected>Yes</option>
  <option value="No">No</option>
</select>
```

See http://www.w3schools.com/tags/tag_option.asp for more information.

When I do things like this, I'll commonly setup an array (something like this) :

```
$aOptions['Yes'] = 'Yes';
$aOptions['No'] = 'No';

foreach ($aOptions AS $cKey => $cValue)
{
  echo "<option value='", $cKey, "'";
  if ($isOpen == $cKey)
  {
      echo " selected";
  }
  echo ">", $cValue, "</option>";
}
```

The benefit being that you can add items to the allowable list easily.